# How do i add custom post types to this query?

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop

I'm using the code below to display the latest post from a certain category but i am using Custom Post Types and I don't know how to insert the custom post type function into this code.

I want to get the latest post from a certain category, from each post type.

So how do i add that to the code below.

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=23' );
// The Loop!
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>

<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()){
    $queryObject->the_post();
    ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('video-post');     ?>
                    </a>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>




<?php
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: please post the full code of your custom loop - all including the `endif;`

Comment: added, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you certain you have posts in category #23?  Try var_dump($queryObject); to see if there's anything there.

Comment: Where do i put that, and yes there are post in category 23, I'm using custom post types as well, and I am using the categories in post types, could that be a cause of conflict

Comment: custom post types in a query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: I'm having trouble with Adding that

Answer (score 0):

`showposts` is replaced with `posts_per_page` (see [Pagination Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters)). Also `orderby` value is invalid (see [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)).

```
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=23' );
```

Comment: This doesn't work